# Python3.10 source venv has changed

Tags: python-venv, python-3.10

I went to do some python leetcode on a personal repo and after I upgraded my Kubuntu to 22.04 I realized the current venv wasn't working.

I had figured I would need to recreate the venv.
Installed python3.10-venv but I cant source and activate it.

In fact venv/bin/activate doesn't exist anymore.

The folder only contains three files

```
python python3 python3.10
```

I had tried but no dice

```
source venv/bin/python3.10
```

So naturally source venv/bin/activate doesn't work. Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've installed Ubuntu 22.0.4 and I've had the same problem as yours and I solved that problem in this way.

install venv:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv`

Create venv:

3. `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.10 (VENV-NAME)`
4. `python3.10 -m venv (VENV-NAME)`
5. `source (VENV-NAME)/bin/activate`

check & update pip:

6. `pip list`
7. and update pip for example(in my pc):
   (`/home/amin/Desktop/prog/Django/moein/coffeinrider.com/Project/A/(VENV-NAME)/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip`)

Comment: Okay I had solved this issue previously but I cant remember exactly lol...I'm going to mark yours as the answer however. Additionally for convenience: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: What? The package name is changed from python3-venv to python3-virtualenv? I've tried python3-venv, and found serious problem on version unmet! Anyone know any difference between venv and virtualenv???? Are they mistakes made by Ubuntu maintaining team?

Answer (score 3):

When trying to create a virtual env using `venv` for Python, a version of Python that is already installed system-wide must be used, but a version of the `venv` library from the system must also be used. These are two pre-requisites for setting up a virtual environment.

**WARNING: I did this in a hurry because I needed it but please be warned: this may break your system Python with a result that applications that rely on it may break.**

The problem I had, matching symptoms given here, seems to be that when trying to create a `venv` using Python 3.10.8, the `venv` module for Python 3.8.10 was being used.

So, given Python 3.8 and Python 3.10 are already installed using `apt`, first of all I uninstalled these packages:

```
sudo apt purge python3-venv python3.8-venv
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I linked `python3` to point to Python 3.10:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm python3
sudo ln python3.10 python3
```

Then I installed the `venv` for Python3.10:

```
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
```

This now means creating a virtual environment for Python 3.8 doesn't work (because Python3.8 `venv` has just been removed). I'm not sure if there is a means to have them both working, and I haven't yet tried to just install `python3.8-venv` again and try them both, as I need my 3.10 environment working quickly, right now ;-). But it seems possible there has been some conflict introduced when following the usual upgrade route within Ubuntu 20.

However, `venv` for Python 3.10 should now work as expected:

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ python -V
Python 3.10.8
(.venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip
...
(.venv) $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3
setuptools 63.2.0
```

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo apt install python3.10-venv`. If apt cannot find an install candidate, you might need to do `sudo apt update` before.

Comment: Wow , This worked for me after struggling for 2 days , Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It has been updated to `source venv/local/bin/activate`