# How to install python3.10 virtual environment when python3.10-venv has no installation candidate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

I had just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, which comes preinstalled with python3.10. I tried creating a virtual environment but it was unsuccessful. Trying to install the virtual env package gets an error `E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate`

```
python3 -m venv newpy310
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.10-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/user/Desktop/pyenvs/newpy310/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

Following which i used `sudo apt install python3.10-venv`, and was returned with

```
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.10-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.10-venv' has no installation candidate
```

Something similar can be encountered if I used `sudo apt install python3.10-virtualenv`

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.10-virtualenv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10-virtualenv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.10-virtualenv'
```

My sudo apt-get update also looks suspicious, but i am not entirely sure if it is the culprit

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                 
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                       
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                  
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_SG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_SG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list:14
```

I also have already added the deadsnakes ppa repos. I noticed some other questions were for python 3.6 or 3.8, which had worked in the past when i was using python 3.6 and 3.8 respectively. However, the methods described within does not work for my current setup with Ubuntu 22.04 and python3.10.

1. [python3.8-venv not working with python3.8 -m venv env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773433/python3-8-venv-not-working-with-python3-8-m-venv-env)
2. [python3.8-venv is no longer working after Pop OS upgraded to 21.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211364/python3-8-venv-is-no-longer-working-after-pop-os-upgraded-to-21-04)
3. [Trouble Installing Python3.6 Virtual Environment on Ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368514/trouble-installing-python3-6-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04)

These are the other links that I have consulted but did not work for me. I have also tried reinstalling python3.10 itself.

1. [How to use Python3.10 on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830431/how-to-use-python3-10-on-ubuntu)
2. [Trouble Installing Python3.6 Virtual Environment on Ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368514/trouble-installing-python3-6-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04)
3. [pyvenv not working because ensurepip is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539110/pyvenv-not-working-because-ensurepip-is-not-available)
4. [pyvenv not working because ensurepip is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539110/pyvenv-not-working-because-ensurepip-is-not-available?noredirect=1&lq=1)
5. https://askubuntu.com/questions/879437/ensurepip-is-disabled-in-debian-ubuntu-for-the-system-python
6. [Python3.10 source venv has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818928/python3-10-source-venv-has-changed)

Q: How to install python3.10 virtual environment when python3.10-venv has no installation candidate?

Comment: i'm having the same distro.. i recreated your steps and it got installed perfectly fine for me

Comment: @Kulasangar does your 'sudo apt-get update' return anything strange? i am not sure if there are any broken packages on my device

Comment: ah no it did not.. yeah that's what I'm also thinking!! can you like do a `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then run the apt-get update?

Comment: @Kulasangar yep i ran that before and the apt-get update still returns the same things

Comment: The warnings indicate you have something funny in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`;  perhaps that is also the explanation for your troubles with this particular package.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with installing `python3.10-venv` on `Ubuntu22.04.1 LTS`

However, the issue was resolved simply by upgrading apt.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Afterwords the `sudo apt install python3.10-venv` worked smoothly.

**Edit:** (about issue with the update)
Sorry I did notice your issue with `apt update`. 
Have you had a look at the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? 
The warning suggests you have duplicate lines in the file.
If so, maybe try removing the duplicates?

However, this should not be an issue.
So please try `sudo apt upgrade` if you haven't already.

Comment: Note the correct commands are: `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

python3.10-venv is typically the package that provides the venv module for creating virtual environments in Python 3.10. If the package is not found when you try to install it, it may mean that it is not available in the package repository for your specific distribution or version of Linux.

One way to create a virtual environment with Python 3.10 is by using the pyenv tool. pyenv allows you to easily install and manage multiple versions of Python on your system. You can install pyenv by following the instructions on the GitHub page: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Once you have pyenv installed, you can install Python 3.10 by running the following command:

```
pyenv install 3.10.0
```

You can the create your environement

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.0 my_env
```

This will create a new virtual environment called my_env that uses Python 3.10.0. To activate the virtual environment, run the following command:

```
pyenv activate my_env
```

Comment: thanks @Serge. I recently found out that the package for the python3.10 venv was added and now can be installed via sudo apt-get update. Nonetheless, the method you wrote works.

Answer (score 0):

Found out from the comments over [here in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830431/how-to-use-python3-10-on-ubuntu/71095440?noredirect=1#comment132924458_71095440) that the problem was because the venv package was not added yet at the time when i wrote the question

Running `sudo apt install python3.10-venv` now allows me to install the package, and i can now make a python3.10 virtual environment on the default Ubuntu 22.04 LTS